# Is there an alternative for the Excel function CONCATENATE that doesn't require text?

Tags: excel, text, concatenation, offset

In excel, I am trying to obtain the average of a range of numbers in a single column with a fixed start row (B4) and a variable end row (which is the value of Cell C2 minus 1 with the match function) I am using the following formula in Excel that works perfectly:

```
=AVERAGE(B4:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",MATCH((C2-1),A:A,0))))
```

HOWEVER, I will need to copy and paste this formula into other columns, so the "B" will need to change to a "G" and so on. The new column letter will always be +5 from the previous column, and -3 from the column the cell formula is stored in. I want Excel to auto-populate the change in column letter, but CONCATENATE only works with text. I tried to use the offset function in place of the CONCATENATE "B" argument (see below), but I think INDIRECT might require text as well and/or I'm using the offset function incorrectly.

```
AVERAGE(B4:INDIRECT((OFFSET(5,-3,0)) & MATCH((C2-1),A:A,0))))
```

Does anyone have any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=AVERAGE(B4:INDEX(B:B,MATCH((C2-1),A:A,0)))
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!